# Cold boot: snapshot failed to load

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Sometimes I start Android Emulator with the GUI, and sometimes I start with the CLI. If I keep using the same method, everything is fine, but if I switch between methods, it causes problems. For example if I start the emulator with the CLI, then shut down, then start again using the GUI, I get this:

```
Cold boot: snapshot failed to load
```

If I start with the GUI, then shut down and start with the CLI, I get this:

```
qemu-system-i386.exe: Failed to load virtio-blk:virtio
```

Here is the command I use with CLI:

```
adb start-server
emulator -writable-system -avd Pixel_2_API_24
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like the emulator processes are not closed properly.
Check if there are any processes **besides** grep --colour=auto emulator, which is the one we create by running:

```
ps -ef | grep emulator
```

Which lists all processes connected to the emulator. 
Now kill every process, except the one I mentioned earlier with:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

I want to mention that my answer is based on another ones I can't find anymore...

If this doesn't help, my issue was an improper graphic driver, why I had to change the **Graphics** from *Automatic* to *Sortware* in the devices **AVD Manager**.